# No puedo acceder a mis DNS desde afuera de mi Servidor CentOS

Tags: linux, windows, servidor, centos, dns

Estimados no puedo lograr ver mis DNS desde el exterior de mi servidor.
Tengo un servidor (No es una maquina virtual) CentOS 6.9 32bits, tengo configurado mis DNS,que dentro del servidor responden bien.
Pero cuando realizo desde mi consola de windows :

```
λ nslookup                                                                                                         
Servidor predeterminado:  UnKnown                                                                                  
Address:  [mi ip]                                                                                             

> www.[mi dominio].com                                                                                                
Servidor:  UnKnown                                                                                                 
Address:  [mi ip]                                                                                              

*** No hay registros internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) disponibles para www.[mi dominio].com    

> ns1.[mi dominio].com                                                                                                
Servidor:  UnKnown                                                                                                 
Address:  [mi ip]                                                                                              

*** No hay registros internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) disponibles para ns1.[mi dominio].com    
>
```

Desde Linux:

[

```
serverroot@server~]$ nslookup
> www.[midominio].com
Server:         [mi ip]
Address:        [mi ip]#53

Name:   www.[mi dominio].com
Address: [mi ip]
> dns.[mi dominio].com
Server:         [mi ip]
Address:        [mi ip]#53

Name:   dns.[mi dominio].com
Address: [mi ip]
> ns1.[mi dominio].com
Server:         [mi ip]
Address:        [mi ip]#53

Name:   ns1.[mi dominio].com
Address: [mi ip]
>
```

Lo que estoy necesitando es direccionar mi dominio goingcode.com a mi servidor, pero no lo estoy logrando por que intento configurar los DNS del dominio me dice que mis DNS no existen.
Mi ip esta configurada para que sea estática desde CentOS.
Asumo que tengo bien configurado mis DNS de

```
/etc/named.conf
/etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Una pregunta mu *chorra*: ¿ Como asignas la IP al Güindo$ ? ¿ Por DHCP ?

Comment: La ip es estatica

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer tu problema radica en que el servidor DNS predeterminado de tu computadora Windows no apunta a tu servidor CentOS.

Suponiendo que tu servidor Windows tiene la IP 192.168.0.1 y que el Centos tiene 192.168.0.2, y que el dominio que quieres consultar se llama www.goingcode.com desde el cmd de Windows ejecuta la siguiente instrucción:

```
nslookup www.goingcode.com 192.168.0.2
```

Si recibes una respuesta como esta es que tu CentOs está resolviendo las peticiones correctamente desde otras computadoras:

```
Servidor:  192.168.0.2
Address:  192.168.0.2

Nombre:  www.goingcode.com
Address:  192.168.0.2
```

Puedes ver desde el cmd tu servidor DNS predeterminado por interfaz usando el comando:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show dnsserver
```

Y cambiarlo usando el siguiente:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "<<nombre de interfaz>>" address=192.168.x.x index=1
```

O bién con los siguientes pasos [de esta página](https://www.elgrupoinformatico.com/como-cambiar-los-dns-windows-t25163.html).